# Vue JS, closing tag linting is broken

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code

Anyone encountered this issue before?

[image]

I've got no errors in any of the outputs and am going through plugins one at a time.  If anyone has seen this it would be great to get some insight.

I'm on:

- Windows 11
- Volar 0.40.1
- Typescript Vue Plugin: 0.40.1 (not typescript in current project howerver)
- VS Code: July 2022 (version 1.70)

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out.  As it turns out the the `lang="html"` attribute in the `template` tag must be removed to make this work.

Funny fact, I actually submitted a ticket to VSCode/Vuter a little while ago where we had broken syntax and determined that a bug made it necessary to include the `lang` tag.

Odd that the bug has flipflopped, so I guess if you (the reader) happen to be a poor soul experiencing this you will need to try both approaches to determine what your combination of VSCode/Vue language support will accept:

TLDR:

```js
//used to require this in SFC's:
<template lang="html">
</template>
```

```
// now requires this with volar
<template>
<template>
```